# Toolbar remains black in android?

Tags: android, material-design

I am working in android material design. I tried to design app, but the **ColorPrimary** changes in every version, but **ColorPrimaryDark** changes only in API level 22.

```
styles.xml  it contains code for styles.xml under the res directory

<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>

    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

`v21\styles.xml` it contains code for v21\styles.xml under the res directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>

    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonColor</item>
</style>
```

```
colors.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <color name="primaryColor">#3F51B5</color>

 <color name="primaryColorDark">#303F9F</color>

 <color name="accentColor">#F44336</color>
 <color name="buttonColor">#F44336</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: please elaborate your question, what do you mean by ColorPrimaryDark changes only in API level 22?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html in this link under the Customize the Status Bar heading you will see a diagram in which you can get the meaning of ColorPrimaryDark